# Automated exporting formulas from OOo Writer

Tags: script, automation, openoffice-writer

I'm frequently writing articles to newspaper, but since formulas doesn't appear there often, they have no way of processing them and I have to provide them as images.

I wrote an article, which have around 50 numbered formulas and a number of formulas embedded in the text. There's no way I'm screenshoting all of them, that will be madness.

Is there a way to automate the following process (or at least its parts):

- Extract all formulas from OOo document (I don't need numbering, formulas themselves will suffice)
- Render them with specified DPI or size?

The desperate plan would be to manually decompress zip file and dig into XMLs, but I hope it won't come to this either.

Answer (score 0):

The Math component does not easily export images.  So instead, copy and paste into LibreOffice Draw, and then export a PNG file from there.

Here is some code to enumerate the Math formula objects.

```
Sub ExportFormulasAsImages
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oEmbed = oDoc.getEmbeddedObjects()
    filenum = 0
    For i = 0 To oEmbed.getCount() - 1
        oObj = oEmbed.getByIndex(i)
        If oObj.supportsService("com.sun.star.text.TextEmbeddedObject") Then
            If oObj.CLSID = "078B7ABA-54FC-457F-8551-6147e776a997" Then
                oFormulaDoc = oObj.getEmbeddedObject().Parent
                oDrawPage = oFormulaDoc.DrawPage(0)
                filenum = filenum + 1
                sURL = "file:///path/formula" & Format(filenum, "00") & ".jpg"
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Exported " & filenum & " formulas as images."
End Sub
```

Example code for copying into Draw and then exporting is at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/141898/macro-for-saving-sheet-as-single-image-in-calc/.

I've left it up to you to work out exactly how to write the code, but feel free to post on StackOverflow or ask.libreoffice.org if you get stuck.  Post the code you have tried so far.

**EDIT**:

A good place to start learning about LibreOffice macros is http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php.

To discover what objects can do, use an introspection tool such as [MRI](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/mri-uno-object-inspection-tool) or [XrayTool](http://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/index2.html).

As far as the API docs, ignore the SwX prefix when writing macros.  These documents are helpful when used together with an introspection tool.  Taken alone, they are difficult to read because of inheritance structure.

- https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/TextEmbeddedObject.html
- https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/servicecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1text_1_1TextEmbeddedObject.html

Recording is not a good way to start learning how to write macros.  However, it is useful for certain dispatcher operations such as copy/paste.  To do this, *Enable experimental features* in *Tools -> Options -> Advanced*.  In LO 6 there is a specific checkbox *Enable macro recording*.  Then *Tools -> Macros -> Record Macro*.

One more thing to consider: For serious work, [Python-UNO](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python) is generally a better way to write macros, because of data structures, regular expressions and file handling for example.  (C++ is possible but not as good for most macros.  Java is a solid choice and sticks closely to the UNO API, but makes some things more difficult than needed).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd gladly carry on developing it further, but I failed to find documentation for LibreOffice macros. The one I found, https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/index.html , does not mention, for instance, SwXTextEmbeddedObject. I also did not find option to record macro, such that I could get a glimpse of were should I find. My current idea is to start Draw from within Writer, embed formula there and attempt to export the drawing to png file.

Comment: Also, LibreOffice's code editor lacks autocompletion, so I cannot even guess, what I may do with the objects in the script...

Comment: @Spook: See edited answer for some tips.